# Font not rendering properly on visited index page in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

This has me completely stumped. I have a website that used a serif font for the header and a sans-serif font for the body text. The index page loads fine in IE9. However, when navigating to other pages and returning to the index page, text is rendered in a serif font. Navigation styles are not affected. 
When the page is refreshed, it displays properly. Only the index page is affected.
This does not happen in any other browser. 
The HTML and CSS have been validated with no errors.

I have tried adding  !important to the sans-serif font in the CSS with no change.
I have tried adding the font declaration to each  element with no change.
The CSS looks like this:

```
#header {
font-family:"Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
}

#section {
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

What makes this more mysterious, is that occassionally, the page performs as expected. 
Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: need to see your more...i'm guessing open sans is @font-face rule? urls?

Comment: The first line of the CSS page is:

Answer (score 0):

could possibly be @imports not downloading sequentially...although they should already be cashed. easy fix would be to generate open sans @font-face rule declaration via font squirrel, place that in your style sheet. or change your initial import to a link element, as well as pulling the google font import statement out and making it a link element as well, placing it above the other style sheet. you can read more here: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the way the CSS sheet was linked within the head. 
Original code:

```
     <style>
     @import url(css/stylesheet.css);
     </style>
```

New declaration:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
```

What made this mysterious was that pages would load correctly and only a couple pages were affected. The problem appeared only after a page was visited and only with Internet Explorer. Thank you Albert, for giving me a clue to solve this.